# Session value not printing other key and their value

Tags: php, session

I can set this session values.

```
<?php
  $_SESSION['cart_items'][$name]['price']=$price;
  if (!empty($quantity)) {
    $_SESSION['cart_items'][$name]['quantity']=$quantity;
  }
?>
```

But when I run this

```
<?php
  foreach($_SESSION['cart_items'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $key ;
    echo $value;
    //echo "<br>prod product_price : ".$product_price;
  }
?>
```

It only prints the `$_SESSION['cart_items'][$name]['price']`. It doesn't not print the quantity value. How can I print like for the `$name` the price, quantity etc.

Here is my full code:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_items'])){
    $_SESSION['cart_items'] = array();
}

// check if the item is in the array, if it is, do not add
if(array_key_exists($id, $_SESSION['cart_items'])){
    // redirect to product list and tell the user it was added to cart
    header('Location: products.php?action=exists&id' . $id . '&name=' . $name);
}

// else, add the item to the array
else{
    $_SESSION['cart_items'][$name]['price']=$price;

    if (!empty($quantity)){
          echo "adding qty";
        $_SESSION['cart_items'][$name]['quantity']=$quantity;
    }

    // redirect to product list and tell the user it was added to cart
   // header('Location: products.php?action=added&id' . $id . '&name=' . $name);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$_SESSION['cart_items'][$name]['quantity']` is being set? I would test first if execution is entering on that conditional

Comment: Yes I tested it firing that condional.

Comment: Add the output of `var_export($_SESSION['cart_items']` on the main post pls

Comment: I do not know all the details what type of var is $name and is $quantity an array?

Comment: here is the output array ( 'Abercrombie Allen Anew Shirt' => '199', 'Abercrombie Allen Brook Shirt' => '10', )? so does this mean it did not set the quantity?

Comment: Try using var_dump($str); to see what is being used.

Comment: Is **$_SESSION['cart_items'][$name]** an array?

Comment: I did this in the begining if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_items'])){
    $_SESSION['cart_items'] = array();
}?

Comment: @user5313398 yes, apparently qty is not being set properly, you should get an array of values per key (name)

Comment: So how to correctly set cause I google some example shown like this.

Comment: You also need to creates an array for `$_SESSION['cart_items'][$name] =[];`

Comment: @user5313398 that's up to you, check your conditional and what you want to do

Comment: @user5313398 yeah, add the code where you're setting the values I think you're missing something there

Comment: @AlexisCôté so mean for everytime I need to create one new $_SESSION['cart_items'][$name] =[]; ?

Comment: I have this if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_items'])){
    $_SESSION['cart_items'] = array();
}
 
// else, add the item to the array
else{
    $_SESSION['cart_items'][$name]['price']=$price;

    if (!empty($quantity)){
       echo "adding qty";
        $_SESSION['cart_items'][$name]['quantity']=$quantity;
    }
 
    // redirect to product list and tell the user it was added to cart
   // header('Location: products.php?action=added&id' . $id . '&name=' . $name);
}

Comment: @user5313398 If you want to set values at `$_SESSION['cart_items'][$name][$key][$value]`,  `$_SESSION['cart_items'][$name]` needs to be an array.

Comment: @user5313398 not there man, in the OP please, edit your post and add the required info so we can help you

Comment: @AlexisCôté I have added my full codes how I define and then how I set it ? Can you tell me where my mistake it ?

Comment: @user5313398 See my answer. You forgot to create an array of the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your new item, you need to create an **Array** at [$name] since an Item is an array for you.
Without doing so, you were trying to assign a value as if it was an array but it was just a simple value.

```
<?php 

    if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_items'])){
        $_SESSION['cart_items'] = array();
    }

    // check if the item is in the array, if it is, do not add
    if(array_key_exists($id, $_SESSION['cart_items'])){
        // redirect to product list and tell the user it was added to cart
        header('Location: products.php?action=exists&id' . $id . '&name=' . $name);
    }

    // else, add the item to the array
    else{
        //Since your item is an array, you need to create it.
        $_SESSION['cart_items'][$name] = array();
        $_SESSION['cart_items'][$name]['price']=$price;

        if (!empty($quantity)){
              echo "adding qty";
            $_SESSION['cart_items'][$name]['quantity']=$quantity;
        }

        // redirect to product list and tell the user it was added to cart
       // header('Location: products.php?action=added&id' . $id . '&name=' . $name);
    }
```

Comment: how to run the for loop such that for the name I want to print its quantity and price and also print the name?

Comment: @How to improvise this section that if there exist an array of $_SESSION['cart_items'][$name] I would want to upgrade the quantity with a new value ?

Comment: @user5313398 you will need two `foreach` loop, one to iterate over `$name` and the second one to iterate over each `$key => $value` under that `$name`

Comment: @ReynierPM I tried this foreach($_SESSION['cart_items'] as $key => $item) {
          echo "name  u is : ".$item;  
         foreach($item as $key2 => $value) {
             echo "value u is : ".$value;
    } 
  } how to echo the name ? I tried cant it just show as array?

Comment: @user5313398 you're hijacking this thread with question that doesn't belongs here. You have your answer accept it and open a new question for your new doubts

Comment: @ReynierPM I will do a new question sorry for the hijacking.

Comment: I said *two foreach loops* because you've multidimensional array

Comment: Yes my first for loop is foreach($_SESSION['cart_items'] as $key => $item) { next is  foreach($item as $key2 => $value) {

Answer (score 1):

You have a multi-dimensional array:

```
$_SESSION['cart_items'][$name]['quantity']=$quantity;
     ^--#1     ^--#2     ^--#3
```

Since this is your foreach:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart_items'] as $key => $value){
               ^--#1                         ^--#2
```

meaning that when you `echo $value`, you're trying to echo an array. You'd need ANOTHER loop to reach that 3rd dimension:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart_items'] as $key => $item) {
              ^--#1                         ^--#2
   foreach($item as $key2 => $value) {
             ^--#2             ^--#3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
  if (!isset($_SESSION['cart_items'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart_items'] = array();
  }
  $z = $_SESSION['cart_items'];
  $q = array_column($z, 'name');
  if (array_key_exists($id, $q)){
    header('Location: products.php?action=exists&id' . $id . '&name=' . $name);
  } else {
    if (!empty($quantity)) {
      array_push($_SESSION['cart_items'], array('name' => $name, 'quantity' => $quantity, 'price' => $price));
    }
    header('Location: products.php?action=added&id' . $id . '&name=' . $name);
  }

?>
```

Then you can echo all items

```
<?php
  $f = $_SESSION['cart_items'];
  $d = array_column($f, 'name');
  $s = array_column($f, 'quantity');
  $t = array_column($f, 'price');
  static $x = 1;
  while (count($d) > $x) {
    echo $d[$x];
    echo $s[$x];
    echo $t[$x];
    $x++;
  }

?>
```